# What programming languages are scopes written in?

Tags: application-development, scopes

I'd like to get started writing a Scope for Ubuntu.

What programming languages are available and what should I choose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once upon a time, scopes had Python and Vala bindings. Python was the recommended language. This actually still applies for the desktop and Unity 7. However, while it will still be around for a bit (i.e. it's still shipped in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), we're phasing out Unity 7 in favour of Unity 8 in the new world where we'll have a single Unity codebase that runs across devices and form factors (e.g. phone and desktop).

So at this point, the **recommendation for new projects is to write scopes for Unity 8**. In Unity 8 **the supported language is C++**. All current [tutorials](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/tutorials/) and [API docs](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/api/) are based on C++.

The reasons for going for C++ are twofold: performance and compatibility with the Qt APIs available throughout the platform.

We do recognize the value of supporting other bindings. While Go is still not on par with the C++ bindings, **you can also already write scopes in Go** ([see the preliminary documentation](http://godoc.org/launchpad.net/go-unityscopes/v1)) and further down the road we're also *considering* adding JavaScript.

Comment: Did the dev team consider Go instead of C or Python? I know that some Ubuntu things (for example, Juju) are written in Go.

Comment: It seems to me that Vala would be a better choice than C since this would make it easier to make it introspectable, enabling the use of other languages as well.

Comment: cool, there are a few api's that seemed to require a bit of javascript to link back on preview pages, so that would be awesome.

Comment: David, your answer was edited in 2014. What is the status of language support for scopes as of 2016  and in the current LTS releases (14.04 and 16.04) ?