# Has the support for the Python language been removed from the SDK?

Tags: python, scopes

Has the support for the Python language been removed from the SDK in Ubuntu 13.10? I can't find any tutorial for the Unity scope and for Python.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I find your question(s) very hard to understand. Bluntly responed: I don't know why you don't find any [tutorials](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91065/how-to-create-a-scope). And: The support for Python hasn't been removed. But I'm very unsure if that is really what your question is aiming at. Could you please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/376633/edit) and ask what you are trying to do and what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I guess (s)he is trying to find some docs about how to write scopes for 13.10 in Python. As far as I can see the page you linked only has information about scopes for 13.04 and earlier or other programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

## Scopes are transitioning to C++

The reason you might find it hard to find official tutorials for python is because Canonical is [transitioning scopes to C++](https://askubuntu.com/a/310670/75166) (this is linked from the [official Cookbook page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/cookbook/)).

You can still [use python to write scopes](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/python-unity-singlet/), but it's not the primary target of Canonical... which is sad, I personally love python.