# How can I create Unity dash integration for my Python script?

Tags: unity, application-development, python, scripts, unity-dash

I have written an awesome script in Python and I seriously think it should help many rookie Ubuntu users out there -- especially for a quick solution/tip. My script searches through AskUbuntu.com and finds you the best answer for your question. Yup, it does work, and it works pretty well.

How it works video:  [Ask - Find the best answer to your questions related to Ubuntu in just 1 second !!! - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRMcT1uwjis)

GitHub Repo: [github: drpaneas/ask](https://github.com/drpaneas/ask)

Now, all I need is to implement my Python script for the Dash instead of the terminal. For example, type a question in the Dash and then my script will print you the outcome. Can you help me to do that or could you please provide me some kind of tutorial or guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is writing a Unity Scope, and probably also a Unity Lens. What Unity Lenses and Scopes are is explained (with helpful screenshots) in an article on [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/112510/supercharge-ubuntus-unity-dash-with-lenses-scopes-5-lenses-to-install/).

The Ubuntu Developer Portal provides an [overview](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/overview/) and also a helpful [tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/tutorial/) on writing Scopes in C. You said your application is written in Python and whilst this is a supported language, it is [recommended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310669/what-programming-languages-are-scopes-written-in) to write scopes in C.

If you still want to write your Scope in Python, the web provides you with a [tutorial](http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/tutorial-on-writing-ubuntu-lensesplaces-in-python/) that makes use of GObject Introspection.