# Mac style application shortcut in KDE (focus existing instance or launch new one)?

Tags: kde, window-management

In osx you can set a shortcut keybinding for any app (using Better Touch Tool), and when you press that key, if the app is not open, it will be opened, otherwise it will be brought in the front. I am wondering how this can be achieved in kde.

Comment: I wrote [this script](http://askubuntu.com/a/507130/81372) for LXDE, but it might work on KDE, too. I'd be glad if you gave it a try.

Comment: Still in early alpha, but what you need is working. https://github.com/mreq/wmctile

Comment: After installation, that would be `wmctile summon_or_run 'appname' 'cmd_to_run'`. Get the proper name by looking at `wmctrl -lx` output. You can bind hotkeys for that by xbindkeys or anything else.

Comment: Awesome! This explains exactly why I like linux so much!