# creating GUIs in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gui

Is there a software tool that allows me to develop GUIs in `ubunu 14.04`

Comment: the Ubuntu SDK to name the one specific for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about graphical front-end to scripting, then you can use `zenity`. For instance, here are some examples from `man zenity`

Open a graphical dialog to select a file:
`zenity  --title="Select a file to remove" --file-selection`

Here's a line to list all files in current working directory and show them in a popup window: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*" -printf "%f\n"  | zenity --list --column="Files"`

And here is one example how I used it in practice to create a simple app launcher: https://askubuntu.com/a/606072/295286

There's other alternatives, too, for instance, `yad` which is called "zenity on steroids"

Comment: I want to develop an interface for a program written with ' linux shell bash ' which must be used

Comment: @AhmedZnouda zenity will be good for bash. There are many tutorials online and examples on this site. If you have any questions, feel free to ask here

Answer (score 0):

Install and use [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/)

```
sudo apt-get install glade
```

[image]

Glade is a RAD tool to enable quick & easy development of user interfaces for the GTK+ toolkit and the GNOME desktop environment.

The user interfaces designed in Glade are saved as XML, and by using the GtkBuilder GTK+ object these can be loaded by applications dynamically as needed.

By using GtkBuilder, Glade XML files can be used in numerous programming languages including C, C++, C#, Vala, Java, Perl, Python,and others.

<sub>[Source](https://glade.gnome.org/)</sub>

Comment: Nice ! Didn't know such tool existed