# What application launchers are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, launcher, customization, alternative, dock

What are some alternative launchers that can be used to launch programs in Ubuntu's default Unity desktop?

Comment: You can get many such as `Docky`, however they will not properly integrate with Unity and you won't be able to get rid of the default Unity Launcher.

Comment: It doesn't have to replace the default launcher. Just want to know if any other ways to launch programs, even from the Launcher itself, like Gnome DO.

Comment: just to mention: http://askubuntu.com/a/606252/72216 with specific functionality :) Should work not only on Unity.

Comment: @JacobVlijm already mentioned that question in my answer bellow ^_0

Comment: This Q&A would be more readable and friendly to users, if rewritten into "one application launcher per answer" style and likely more easier to update as "Community Wiki". This way, we can avoid duplicates also. Good example is [this related post](http://askubuntu.com/q/35488/37165).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Docky** is a great app, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install docky
```

[image: Docky]

---

**GNOME Pie** is another great one that can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-pie
```

[image]

(Launch with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> - this hot key is customizable.)

---

**Cairo-Dock** is also good, and can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

[image: Cairo-Dock]

---

**Plank** is another good one that can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install plank
```

[image: Plank]

Comment: I may update this answer with more.

Answer (score 12):

One that I use and like is [Albert](https://github.com/ManuelSchneid3r/albert).

It's very similar to OS X's Spotlight Search, especially in how it looks, but I've found it to be invaluable if you're a keyboard-heavy power user.

[image]

You have to install it via a PPA (not in the official repos yet):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/albert
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install albert
```

On the first launch you will have to set the hotkey to launch Albert, but that's fairly easy:

[image]

I've set it to `Ctrl-Space`.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some more ways to launch and organize applications:

**GnomeDO**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-do gnome-do-plugins
```

[image]

**Duck Launcher**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:the-duck/launcher
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install duck-launcher
```

[image]

**Launcher Folders**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:asukhovatkin/unity-launcher-folders
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-launcher-folders
```

[image]

**Slingscold Launcher**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slingscold
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You also have **dockbarx**. You can install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dockbar-main/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install dockbarx
```

[image]

More info [here](https://github.com/M7S/dockbarx).

Answer (score 3):

My personal favorite is the [Classic Menu Indicator](https://launchpad.net/classicmenu-indicator)

[image]

In addition to other answers, me and @JacobVlijm  have tried to script launchers as an answer to  [Launch app only if not already open](https://askubuntu.com/q/440142/295286) question

Comment: Now I know why you're not in the chat room: in the mean time, your battery ran out!  **:D**

Comment: @Fabby actually this screenshot is not from my desktop, but my battery is really running out , so had to be quick. Also I'm not in the chat because i am running around, covering people

Comment: @Serg Thanks for mentioning :) How could I overlook...

Answer (score 2):

Gnome-Do works with the keyboard as Unity. Press Super + Space and then you type the name of the program you want to run. Don't know about the project status and haven't used it since 2009. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 2):

Consider Synapse:

[image]

Just start typing the program, file or directory you're looking for.

Installation:

```
sudo apt install synapse
```

Answer (score 1):

[`lxqt-runner`](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-runner) is an option:

[image]

Installation: `sudo apt install lxqt-runner`

Answer (score 0):

**Cairo Dock** has launchers too.

To install it click below

[Cairo Dock](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cairo-dock) [image: Install banshee]

I use **Compiz** with Cairo dock so I use it in *fall back mode*. It adds a session for **cairo only environment** if you don't want to use Unity

Answer (score 0):

My recent favorite: the very very lightweight [`dmenu`](https://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/)

Installation:

```
sudo apt install dmenu
```

Improve that tool with [`dmenu-extended`](https://github.com/MarkHedleyJones/dmenu-extended) to be able to find files and directories from dmenu, too. Very useful.

```
sudo apt install suckless-tools xfonts-terminus
git clone git@github.com:MarkHedleyJones/dmenu-extended.git
cd dmenu-extended
sudo python setup.py install
```