# Will the new Ubuntu finally have a menu that is workable?

Tags: unity

will the new Ubuntu finally have a Menu structure that is workable?
So you do not have to remember every program name you have ever installed?
So that a link is easy created on your workbench.

The way it is now with Unity is most stupid i've ever seen. And drives me right back were i came from, indeed windows.

Do something with it, something logical, something that works easy. Humans are spoiled i know. If you want to win territory you have to make it more easy. This long menu on the left side looks nice but is limited when it comes to easy.
People want to access their programs quickly and not having to look for it like: Where the H*LL did it go???

So please change the way Unity is working now and get winning again.

Thanks!

JJS

Comment: If you want Windows then use Windows. Linux is for someone who wants something different. Linux is not Windows, thankfully. If you came to Linux expecting to find it looks like, works like, and is like Windows then you'll be sorely disappointed and you might just as well have not wasted your time or our time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unity Dash is indeed something very different from what e.g. Windows users are used to. But you can also let the Dash's application lens (<kbd>Super</kbd>+A) filter the shown items by categories, like to only show games:

[image]

Or if you don't like that at all, switch to e.g. **Xubuntu**, which uses another desktop environment called **XFCE** that is more similar to what you know from Windows (start menu etc.) and is also more lightweight.

You can simply add that DE by installing the package `xubuntu-desktop` and then select which one to use on every login.

Comment: Ok i will try to add xubuntu layer to it. I have seen the filter you mention. But who wants to search every time for their program. I want to see it and click it. Yes it is different, its almost unworkable. Its taking unnecessary time to search for it. If it was easier it could win many more people using it. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Also without going that minimal, the closest to Windows is probably Cinnamon; KDE is also similar to Windows (but it's also pretty much bloated); in the middle there's MATE (similar to GNOME Classic).

Comment: @jjsjjs Well, the programs I really use often can be counted with one or maybe two hands and all of them fit onto the launcher bar. For everything else, it's ok. I agree with you that a menu where all application are ordered into these categories by default is more user-friendly for most people.

Comment: @kos You're probably right, I just did not want to recommend anything I don't use myself - and I only used XFCE for a while.

Comment: I've tried them all, personally I loved Cinnamon; I'd really recommend it in case someone wants something similar to Windows. @jjsjjs If this answer helped you remember that you can accept it by clicking the grey tick under the votes count.

Comment: Great answers! thank you all. I wrote the suggestions down. Lets first try Xubuntu and see how that works. I transferred all my email from Thunderbird to Ubuntu, and works perfect. So that's good! I will keep my Windows partition especially for Audio, because creating music is still not as good as on windows or Mac. But actually it should become as good as on the Mac. Because Mac is based on Linux.  And i will try 2 run LAMP or so, now i use easyphp on windows for maintaining and testing a few websites i manage for others. I use Livecode to create x-platform-software,need windows to test. thx!

Comment: @jjsjjs "*I transferred all my email from Thunderbird to Ubuntu*" What? You can continue to use your old Windows Thunderbird profile on Ubuntu. Just move the profile directory and set it up with `thunderbird -P`. And I doubt you won't find audio processing tools for Ubuntu that can do less than those you used on Windows.

Comment: @kos I had Cinnamon for a few weeks as well, but then it crashed and refused to work on my main user account. Had to remove it again... :-(

Comment: Ah. It worked fine on Debian, but probably it's better integrated in Debian than Ubuntu since Cinnamon is one of the "offical" options.

Comment: @jjsjjs No, OS X (Apple) is not based on Linux. OS X is a UNIX-like OS, it is based on NeXTSTEP which is based on the Mach kernel. It also has some BSD code in it, kernel layers and some user-land stuff, as I recall. Actually, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X#History), I'll use a search engine for you. That will let you know what the Mac is based on. Mac is not now, nor has it ever been, based on Linux. You'll figure it out, in time. Best of luck. I'd suggest one of the Linux for Beginner type books.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I do not understand why would Ubuntu need to cater to the Windows users needs. You don't see Apple doing that, do you ? Windows and Ubuntu are different systems, hence will have different behavior and different organization. I understand people may be spoiled beings, but when you switch systems be prepared to learn a little bit; or in other words: "When in Rome, try to pick up some Italian, don't expect people to speak English".

As for the programs, the core of the question. Byte commander has already provided you with the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, which works well for the 90% of applications that have a `.desktop` file in the `/usr/share/applications` folder ( which by the way, has nothing to do with Ubuntu, it's up to developers to properly package their software and to include that as one of the things ). You can refer to the following question that has been asked on AU long time ago: [What is the equivalent to the Windows “Program Files” folder? (Where do things go when I install them?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/27213/295286)

If you absolutely despise Unity's Dash, remember that you are on Linux ! There is plenty of alternatives. Refer to [What application launchers are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/695054/295286) There is plenty of alternative launchers, docks, menus to choose from.  In addition, there's [alternative Desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/295286)