# Desktop for Ubuntu (14.04) that has horizontal launch bar?

Tags: desktop-environments

I have been trying different desktop environments for Ubuntu 14.04LTS as I am not a huge fan of Unity.
Is there a desktop environment that has a horizontal launch bar, across the bottom? 
The closest I have found is an Apple imitation and all I want is the launch bar, not the rest of the Apple theme.
I feel like I have seen one somewhere but cannot figure out where or what it was.

Comment: You will be able to move unity launcher to the bottom in Xenial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Both are often suggested to newcomers from the Windows world. Also `icewm` or `razorqt` which you can install from repositories with `sudo apt-get install icewm` or `sudo apt-get install razorqt-desktop`

Gnome can also be tweaked to have its internal launcher appear at the bottom.

If you still want to use Unity, its launcher can be configured to auto hide (in Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior ) and install plank or cairo dock.

[image]

And here's the look with plank and minus the launcher
[image]

See also [What application launchers are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/695054/295286)
 as well as [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/295286)

Comment: I just installed Cairo dock, however the Unity launch bar on the LHS is still present. How do I hide it?

Comment: @RossSatchell see my edits. If you find my answer helpful, leave an upvote. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Cinnamon that looks more like a Windows Desktop. 
Use these [steps](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/07/new-cinnamon-ubuntu-14-04-ppa-stable) to install it.